# How to add tileset from cache in CesiumJS

Tags: angular, cesiumjs

I have an angular application and I need to add a tileset that I retrieve from my own api

```
const viewer = new Viewer('cesiumContainer');
this.http.get('URL_TILESET_JSON').subscribe(tile => {
  this.http.get('URL_FILE_B3DM', { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(bd3m=> {
    const tileset = new Cesium3DTileset({
      url: tile
    } as any);

    viewer.scene.primitives.add(tileset);

    tileset.readyPromise.then(function () {
      viewer.zoomTo(tileset);
    });
  })
})
```